# Python Text Clean remove hyperlink

Tags: python, regex, text-mining

I work on a small text mining project.  I have some issues with text pre-processing. There are some text contains the hyperlink without"https", for example:
"For more information, please visit us www.doctorpaul.org"
I want to remove this kind of hyperlink

```
text = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/.*\/\w*', ' ', text)
text = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]{0,62}(/.[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]{0,62})+/.?', ' ', text)
```

however, it doesn't work well. Please let me know how to remove this kind of dirty words in my corpus.

Thanks for any hint and answers!

Comment: Hi! Could you include some examples of text that your regex does and does not match?

Comment: Hi, I got the thing like "www doctorpaul org" , I want to remove all this kind of hyperlink without "https：//" start with. Thanks for answering.

Comment: You could use `text.startsWith("https://")` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith